# Can I link to content dynamically from a page to a new page?

Tags: permalinks, pages, advanced-custom-fields, links

I am new to Wordpress dev, and I have a page that loops through some custom fields(repeater) of people.

I'd like each subfield link to go to another page that has more info from that person on the previous page(same field group data). Is there a dynamic way to do this or do I need to create a new page for each person to show more details on link click?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, maybe you could provide some more details (or an example)?

Comment: @Pim For example, I have a page and I'm using acf field group that holds data related to each person. I'd like to have a link under that person (on the initial page) that goes to a new page that shows more information about that person. So the field group contains the person name, age, hobbies, and career. On the Initial page it will show name and age, and a link saying something like 'read more' that will go to another page that has more of the person info from the field group - hobbies and career.

Comment: I know I can make a page for each person but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without hardcoding a page for each person as more people can be added.

Comment: I don't immediately see a way you could do this. Maybe you could have a "read more" that displays more info with jQuery on the same page? Not sure that's what you want to achieve by displaying this on a second page.

Comment: ah ok, I would need to link to a new page. Thanks, for the suggestion though

Comment: You would at least need to create one page where you can list all the info, and then in the php template change that info based on the page you're linking from. That would be the same link for all pages though. You could add some get data like `/the-new-page?id=123`, and add rewrite rules so it has a different URL. Otherwise you would need to create new pages for every person.

Comment: Thanks, @Pim, could you elaborate a bit more or point me to some information supporting that approach? If I have the same link on the person page and pass in a unique id for each link how could I set the page being linked to only show that related information? Is the id the key?

Comment: I've added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using this as my link, then doing a check on name to show the correct data in the new template:

```
 <a class="btn" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'n', $name, site_url( '/person-info/' ) ) )?>">Read more</a>
```

And updating functions.php:

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "n";
    return $vars;
  }
  add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You would at least need to create one page where you can list all the info. In the php template for that page, you can then change that info based on the page you're linking from.

That would be the same link for all pages though (you could get around that with rewrite rules, but that's a different story).

Say you're linking from a page with ID = 123. Create a new page "The New Page".

In your link you can do something like:

```
<a href="/the-new-page?id=<?php the_ID(); ?>">Read More</a>
```

In the template file of the new page, you add something like:

```
$previous_page_id = $_GET['id'];

$value = get_field('my-field', $previous_page_id);

if($value){
  echo $value;
} else {
  echo 'Sorry, no information found.';
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, the page id would be arbitrary in my case since the page already contains all the person field data. In the loop that displays each link I need to pass a unique identifier for that set of data to then add a conditional in the-new-page template, right?

Comment: You pass on the original page's ID in the link, so that you can retrieve the field data that's on that page.

Comment: The page template already has a loop, since there's a different title, different content, etc... for each page. Simply add the code above with `the_ID()`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, there's one page(id-123) that has all person data(person a, person b, person c). On the-new-page?id123 if I click the link under person a I'm passing in the array thats on page 123 I'm just looping through person a, person b, and person c instead of just showing person a data. Thats my understanding from the above code, unless I'm missing something? I'm wondering if I can pass the person object itself or some paramaters to the new page.